I need advice about my field supervisor at my internship
I started my split internship through my masters program in May. Everything seemed to be going fine with me and my field supervisor. At the end of the semester, she gave me an A and I passed the first half of my field split internship.
Now I am in my second semester of my field split and my midterm evaluation is coming up. My field supervisor, on my midterm evaluation, said I am performing “under expectations”.
But last semester she said I was doing good. I’m not sure what changed. She also puts me down every chance she gets. I thought it was all in my head at first but it has been constant. She even took one of “my” clients away and provided zero feedback as to why. She also said she is not letting me have any more clients. She says I am behind in my learning, but hasn’t given me any other information on what I need to do. In a one on one meeting I had with her, she told me that I won’t make it as a social worker, discouraging me even more.
Everyone else at the internship seems to like me and actually takes the time to teach me. I don’t know how I got on her bad side but now she is threatening to fail me.
I’m at a loss and completely discouraged. I don’t know what to do.

Ask her to give you an 1:1  meeting to discuss your job status, and how to improve your job performance.
Specifically, ask her what she thinks you should improve on. Ask her to give specific examples of your weakness (in her opinion), and then ask her for specific steps that you need to take to improve.

You do not really ask a specific question, but you seem to imply one:

What do I do if I am being given "poor performance" evaluations/feedback but I am not given guidance or details that indicate this or how to fix it?

Your master's program should have administration that sets up and monitors internships. If this is the case, they can advise on something like this.
If you self-selected the internship, then you may need to talk to your school about how to handle this abrupt change in feedback and lack of guidance.
Sometimes internships have to be reset or changed, maybe due to factors outside of your control. For example, your field supervisor may actually be underperforming while trying to blame you, or at least frame you for their poor performance.
You should find a way to engage your school to help sort this out, and to get specific guidance on the claims of your underperformance. What you need to focus on is getting your degree and a good reference, and right now you are stressed because it feels like both are at risk.
